# Batch measuring area and lengths of curves in ImageJ

Tags: image, image-processing, batch-processing, imagej

[Here is my reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RDR9.jpg), StackOverflow won't allow me to embed it into this post.

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to use ImageJ or other free software to measure the length of all the red curves (in mm) and the area of the blue shape (in square mm), standardized to the length of the green scale bar (1 mm).

If it would be possible to automatically get these measurements for batches of images, that would be ideal. I could use different colors if that would make this task easier.

Thank you very much for any feedback that you can provide.

Comment: It's definitely possible to do this in ImageJ. You can segment the image on the basis of color and get the measurements you want. For the red curves, you should take a look at "skeletonize" of the segmented image. Once you have a method that works for one image, it's straightforward to do the same for all images in a directory. Note that your question is a bit open-ended for SO and might get deleted. Questions here need to be more directed, e.g. my code is giving me this error - how do I fix it? https://forum.image.sc is better for general guidance. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It definitely can, but it's going to take learning about a lot of different tools in ImageJ (e.g., segmentation, ROI manager, particle analysis, Measurements, Shape Filter plugin, ImageJ Macros). The good news is that there are a lot of resources online for doing exactly these types of tasks. Learning about segmentation is the best place to start [Segmentation in ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Segmentation). After that I'd read about [Particle Analysis](https://imagej.net/Particle_Analysis). Once you've practiced a bit doing this by hand with one image, then I'd dig into ImageJ macro language to learn about writing code to automate the process for just a single image, and then move into batch processing [Image J Macro Language](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html) .

It may seem like a big investment of time but IMHO it's pretty fun and rewarding work. Automating data analysis (the image you shared looks like a drosophila wing, so I'm guessing you'll be doing a lot of these measurements) can really make your life easier while also leading to more robust/reproducible results.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is extremely helpful.